# Looking for book about a person who was given plastic surgery to look like a super weapon creator

Tags: identification-request

I recently read a fiction book about a British person who woke up in a hotel room looking like a completely different person. He was drugged and given plastic surgery so that he would resemble a scientist that was working on a super weapon. It's a very good book but for the life of me I can't figure out what this book is or find a copy. I thought it was called "Tightrope walkers" or some variation but googling the name gives me a completely different book. Does anyone know what this book is called?

Comment: Welcome to Lit.SE! This is great start to a question. If you could when you read the book/when it was published, any cover art, character names, etc. can help our experts help you in the search. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I am unsure about these details. I read the book last winter, it was on a "take a book, leave a book" rack at a hotel, so I am assuming it is not new. If I was to take a guess, I would say it was published in the 90's or earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Tightrope Men](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1218914.The_Tightrope_Men) by Desmond Bagley

> Giles Denison's life is turned upside down when he awakes to find
>   himself in a luxurious hotel in Oslo and, peering into the bathroom
>   mirror, discovers the face of another man! He has been kidnapped from
>   his flat in London and transformed into famous Finnish scientist, Dr
>   Harold Feltham Meyrick. Compelled to adjust to his new persona
>   (including meeting his daughter) and to play out the role assigned to
>   him by his captors, he embarks on a dangerous escapade from Norway to
>   Finland and across the border into Soviet Russia.

Comment: Wow, Thank you. That is the one!